# Remove and show items in dropdown list in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I want items in dropdownlist(present inside gridview) to be removed when selectedindexchanged event occurs for any of dropdown.So for eg. I have 5 items that are same in 3 dropodownlist, if 1st dropdown is changed to 1st item, I want there be only 4 items in remaining two dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddMapping" CssClass="DDAttributeField DDAttributeFieldNew DD_detailSelect" DataTextField="Name"
                                Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddMapping_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="DO NOT IMPORT" Value="-1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="SKU/Product ID" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Catalog" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Collection" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Display Order" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Name" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>


public void ddMapping_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlCurrentDD = (DropDownList)sender;
        string selected = ddlCurrentDD.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

Edit:I have got the selected index value now i want to hide this from other dropdowns

Comment: Do you want to post some code - or do you want someone to simply write the solution for you? The simple answer is that on the selectedindex_changed event of any of the dropdowns do a postback and rebind the gridview with the dropdownlists showing whatever you want.

Comment: @Mitesh Vora: you can do it using jquery. if you want it in jquery then i have answer.

Comment: @AmitKumar: Sure..not a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add a class(name as **ddlSelect**) to all 3 dropdownlists
like

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="ddlSelect">`  ......

now write this query, as you have mention   **I want there be only 4 items in remaining two dropdownlist**  ,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ddlSelect').on('change', function () {
                var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
                $('.ddlSelect').find('option').show();
                $('.ddlSelect').not(this).find('option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks..that's what i was looking for..was on track for solution and u posted it at same time..thanks a lot..